# Drag and drop multiple rows in MatTable with Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, drag-and-drop, mat-table

I have two Mat-Tables in my Angular project. Drag and drop with single rows works fine. But I need drag and drop with multiple rows, each checked by a checkbox. Cant find any examples on how to do this. Can anyone please help?

Thank you!

Comment: So your are drag from one mat-table and drop it to another mat-table or same mat-table ?

Comment: Both. I can resort the items in one table or drag them over to the other table.

Answer (score 1):

I found some working examples here: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/13807